# MySQL Query To find Trains between two stations

Tags: mysql, sql

My Train Details table,

```
Table Name- traindetailtb

Id  Train_Number  Train_Name       From   To
1    27658         Venad Express    ABC   XYZ
2    27659         Venad Express    XYZ   ABC
```

and my Train Days Table,

```
Table Name- traindaystb
Id  Train_Number Days
1    27658       Sunday
2    27658       Wednesday
3    27659       Saturday
4    27659       Friday
```

and this my Train Schedule Table,

```
Table Name- scheduletb
Id  Train_Number  Station  Time
1    27658          ABC     09:00am  
2    27658          CDE     10:00am
3    27658          XYZ     11:00am
4    27659          XYZ     12:00pm
5    27659          CDE     01:00pm
6    27659          ABC     02:00pm
```

There will be two input, From and To

I need a query that gives all Trains(ie,Train_Number,Train_Name,Days) between the given stations

For eg:
For input From- CDE To-XYZ ---->
 output will be-- 27658    Venad Express    S W

and For input From- XYZ To-CDE   ----> 
output will be--     27659    Venad Express    M T

Can anyone Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT q.train_number, MAX(t.train_name) train_name, GROUP_CONCAT(LEFT(d.days, 1)) days
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.train_number
    FROM scheduletb s JOIN scheduletb e
      ON s.train_number = e.train_number
   WHERE s.station = 'CDE' -- from
     AND e.station = 'XYZ' -- to
     AND s.id < e.id
) q JOIN traindaystb d
    ON q.train_number = d.train_number JOIN traindetailtb t
    ON q.train_number = t.train_number
 GROUP BY q.train_number
```

Output for `CDE -> XYZ`:

```
| TRAIN_NUMBER |    TRAIN_NAME | DAYS |
|--------------|---------------|------|
|        27658 | Venad Express |  S,W |
```

Output for `XYZ -> CDE`:

```
| TRAIN_NUMBER |    TRAIN_NAME | DAYS |
|--------------|---------------|------|
|        27659 | Venad Express |  S,F |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/584ac/11)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t.Train_Number,t.Train_Name,d.Days
from traindetailtb t,traindaystb d 
WHERE 
t.Train_Number=d.Train_Number AND From='ABC' AND To='XYZ';
```

and just read the input and put it into the from=' ' and to=' ';

this single query will return both the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT A.Train_number, A.Train_name, C.days
FROM traindetailtb A, traindaystb B, scheduletb C
WHERE C.Train_Number = A.Train_Number
AND A.Train_Number = B.Train_Number
AND FROM = 'ABC' AND TO = 'XYZ';
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest as follow :

```
select 
    traindetailtb.Train_Number,
    traindetailtb.Train_Name,
    traindetailtb.From,
    traindetailtb.To,
    tranddaystb.Days,
    scheduletb.Time
From 
    traindetailtb 
join trandaystb on
    traindetailtb.Train_Number=traindaystb.Train_Number 
join scheduletb on
    traindetailtb.Train_Number=scheduletb.Train_Number and
    traindetailtb.From=scheduletb.From
where 
    traindetailtb.From=$inputFrom
    and 
    traindetailtb.To=$inputTo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join you can do this, assuming that the Time is really a time field

```
SELECT a.Train_Number, d.Train_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(e.Days)
FROM scheduletb a
INNER JOIN scheduletb b
ON a.Train_Number = b.Train_Number
AND b.Time > a.Time
INNER JOIN traindetailtb d
ON a.Train_Number = d.Train_Number
INNER JOIN traindaystb e
ON a.Train_Number = e.Train_Number
WHERE a.Station = 'CDE'
AND b.Station = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY a.Train_Number, d.Train_Name
```

assuming that you have a real time field for the time

If you wanted only the trains that went directly from CDE to XYZ with no intermediate stations you could add a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the table looking for stations with a time between the other 2:-

```
SELECT a.Train_Number, d.Train_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(e.Days)
FROM scheduletb a
INNER JOIN scheduletb b
ON a.Train_Number = b.Train_Number
AND b.Time > a.Time
LEFT OUTER JOIN scheduletb c
ON a.Train_Number = c.Train_Number
AND c.Time > a.Time 
AND c.Time < b.Time
INNER JOIN traindetailtb d
ON a.Train_Number = d.Train_Number
INNER JOIN traindaystb e
ON a.Train_Number = e.Train_Number
WHERE a.Station = 'CDE'
AND b.Station = 'XYZ'
AND c.Station IS NULL
GROUP BY a.Train_Number, d.Train_Name
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to visualize the days in one single cell instead of spread into multiple rows, use `GROUP_CONCAT`, which acts as a aggregator-function.

```
select tde.train_number, tde.train_name, GROUP_CONCAT(tda.days, ",") as days
from traindetailtb tde
join traindaystb tda on tda.train_number=tde.train_number
where tde.from = $user_input_from
and tde.to = $user_input_to
group by tde.train_number, tde.train_name
```